# Usage of FIND_IN_SET in query

Tags: php, codeigniter, group-by, find-in-set

```
  $query=$this->db
->select(a.date,group_concat(s.name)
->from("tbl_attendance a,tbl_students s") 
->WHERE ("FIND_IN_SET(s.student_id, a.attendance)")->group_by("a.date")
->get();
```

I wanted to know whether I have used the FIND_IN_SET and group_by functions correctly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FIND_IN_SET() returns the position of a string if it is present (as a
>   substring) within a list of strings

so you should search if a value is != 0

eg:

```
->where("FIND_IN_SET(s.student_id, a.attendance) !=", 0)
->group_by("a.date")
```

Comment: I have applied the suggested solution but if I am adding `,0)` it doesn't show the result. without zero at the end, it works. any suggestion regarding this problem? @scaisEdge

Comment: @ankitsuthar   post a new specific question well documented  and with proper code  .. and comment me the question link  ..  so i can evaluate your real situation  ..

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729241/difference-between-where-in-and-find-in-set) is the link sir @scaisEdge