# difference between where_in and find_in_set

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-in, find-in-set

I am working on a join query in which I have to get the data from a column which contain the comma separated values.like `allowed_activity` contain `1,2,3,4,5,6`
this the `activity_id` which is allowed.

So In the query, I am checking that current activity is allowed or not and for that, I have used `where_in` and also tried `find_in_set` in `where` condition.

Here is that part of the query:

```
$this->db->where_in('a.allowed_activity',$activity_id);
//And With FIND_IN_SET
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET($activity_id, a.allowed_activity) !=",0);
```

#### Problem or Confusion

When I use `where_in` it doesn't give me the result. But if I use  `FIND_IN_SET` then it will return the desired result. I thought that `where_in` can do the task but it didn't.

> Just Want to know why `find_in_set` working differently than
>   `where_in`
>   Because of both the function work same as finding the data is in comma separated list.

Here is the complete query:

```
SELECT mycolumns
FROM `table1` as `ea`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` as `a` ON `ea`.`package_id` = `a`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table3` as `e` ON `ea`.`employer_id` = `e`.`id`
WHERE `ea`.`card_id` > 0
AND FIND_IN_SET(6, a.allowed_activity) !=0
AND `ea`.`id` = '6'
ORDER BY `ea`.`creation_date` DESC
```

I am using Codeigniter Active record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE IN` requires the set of values to be specified literally in the query, not as a single value containing a comma-delimited string. If you write:

```
WHERE 6 IN (a.allowed_activity)
```

it will treat `a.allowed_activity` as just a single value, and compare it with `6`, not as a set of multiple values to search.

`FIND_IN_SET` searches a comma-delimited string for the value.

Another way to view it is that `IN` is a shortcut for a bunch of `=` tests combined with `OR`:

```
WHERE x IN (a, b, c, d)
```

is short for

```
WHERE x = a OR x = b OR x = c OR x = d
```

When you rewrite it like this, you can see clearly why it won't work with a column containing a comma-delimited string. It simply translates

```
WHERE 6 IN (a.allowed_activity)
```

to:

```
WHERE 6 = a.allowed_activity
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is incorrect:

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET($activity_id, a.allowed_activity) !=",0);
```

I'm surprised this even runs without error, but one possibility is that it is generating a `WHERE` clause which compares a string against 0.  Of course, they will never be equal, and so this will always be true.

If you want to call the native `FIND_IN_SET()` function, then you would need to use `whereRaw()`:

```
$this->db->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET($activity_id, a.allowed_activity) !=0");
```

Using `WHERE IN (...)` is incorrect here, because you have all the values in a single row, separated from commas.  `WHERE IN` would make sense if you wanted to filter for certain values from many rows, each column having a single value.

Comment: `whereRaw` is not making any difference sir, it gives the same result as `where` @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Update your question with the full Laravel query you are running.  Whence is that `a` alias you are using?  My guess is that your code is the problem.

Comment: Sir, I am using CodeIgniter

Answer (score 1):

`FIND_IN_SET`  search for a value in a array and return the index of the value then if the function is different than 0 this mean that the value in present in the list .
   so the code

```
  this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(6, a.allowed_activity) !=",0);
```

mean return the index of the value 6 in a.allowed_activity
and if the value return is different that 0 then the value 6 is present in  a.allowed_activity

`WHERE ... IN`  check if the value in the set  but don't return the index .. just return  true or false if the value is present or not